# update NSView automatically with the function swift

Tags: swift, drawing, updates, nsview

I have a custom NSView with some drawing:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var mainView: LineDrawer!
var time = NSTimer()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.needsDisplay = true
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
    didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
    }
}


}


class LineDrawer : NSView {
required init?(coder  aDecoder : NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

var lastPt : CGPoint!
var newPt : CGPoint!
var tmp = CGPoint()
override func viewWillDraw() {
    super.viewWillDraw()
    lastPt = newPt
}

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    super.drawRect(dirtyRect)
    self.needsDisplay = true
    NSColor.redColor().set()
    var newLinear = NSBezierPath()
    newLinear.moveToPoint(NSMakePoint(newPt.x, newPt.y))
    newLinear.lineToPoint(NSMakePoint(tmp.x, tmp.y))
    newLinear.lineWidth = 1
    newLinear.stroke()
    println(1)
}

override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseDown(theEvent)
    let location = theEvent.locationInWindow
    lastPt = theEvent.locationInWindow
    tmp = lastPt
}

override func mouseDragged(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseDragged(theEvent)
    newPt = theEvent.locationInWindow
    self.drawRect(self.frame)
    tmp = newPt

}

}
```

It works, but lines appear only after hiding and bringing the window back. I'm looking for the code to write in `updateTheView` function to make the view update every time the mouseDragged is activated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the NSBezier `stroke` in the `drawRect`, not in the `mouseDragged`. Save the coordinates in `mouseDragged` in an instance array and then do the final drawing with Bezier in `drawRect`.

`drawRect` is called by the OS when the view needs display (either being told by `needsDisplay = true` from somewhere or when the window is moved). In the mouse-move routine just store the path. Then when it comes to drawing `drawRect` will actually draw the line.

```
class LineDrawer : NSView {
  var newLinear = NSBezierPath()

  override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    NSColor.redColor().set()
    newLinear.lineWidth = 1
    newLinear.stroke()
  }

  override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseDown(theEvent)
    let location = theEvent.locationInWindow
    var lastPt = theEvent.locationInWindow
    lastPt.x -= frame.origin.x
    lastPt.y -= frame.origin.y
    newLinear.moveToPoint(lastPt)
  }

  override func mouseDragged(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    super.mouseDragged(theEvent)
    var newPt = theEvent.locationInWindow
    newPt.x -= frame.origin.x
    newPt.y -= frame.origin.y
    newLinear.lineToPoint(newPt)
    needsDisplay = true
  }
}
```

I tested it with a plain view in a window.

Comment: I copied your code, but now it doesn't work at all. Lines don't appear even after hiding/bringing back

Comment: BTW, drawRect function works only once at the start of app in your code

Comment: Xcode also showed me an error for NSBezier(), so i replaced it with NSBezierPath()

Comment: This is pretty much what I had in the sample code I provided >.<

Comment: Maybe, but it looks like Obj-C :-) I wrote above in a couple of minutes myself.

Comment: Oh god, I didn't understand the obj-c comment he had before. Do not tell me people are learning swift and can't read back and forth between obj-c and swift. Oh my we are in for a fun ride if that's the case.

Comment: I guess there are quite a couple of people that come in newly with Swift (this guy here definitely). I mean even old Obj-C guys come with questions about converting Obj-C. People have different levels.

Comment: I guess so, I'm just baffled at the fact that people are jumping into Swift without the expectations of needing to understand Obj-c. The fact of the matter is, if you're to develop apps for Apple platforms you have to know obj-c first. The frameworks are still written in obj-c and there's far too much legacy to justify learning swift first at this point. I can't see someone getting a professional job where they'll just need to know Swift, that's just not likely until 2ish or more years pass from now. That's why I'm baffled and take the knowledge for granted.

Comment: I guess Apple' strategy is to get new programmers aboard with sole Swift knowledge. They are working on making the docu cover all Swift and most likely we'll see large parts of NS rewritten in Swift soon(?) and replaced by UI where applicable. Alas, we know YMMV ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You're most likely not calling a method like setNeedsDisplay on the views to force a re drawing on the screen (this would be called when you hide/show the view again forcing the view to re draw itself). Here's a useful link if you don't know a view's life cycle that will help you with custom drawing:

[raywenderlich custom controls](http://www.raywenderlich.com/76433/how-to-make-a-custom-control-swift)

[setNeedsDisplay()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setNeedsDisplay:)

> Discussion
>   Whenever the data or state used for drawing a view object changes, the view should be sent a setNeedsDisplay: message. NSView objects marked as needing display are automatically redisplayed on each pass through the application’s event loop. (View objects that need to redisplay before the event loop comes around can of course immediately be sent the appropriate display... method.)

[Sample drawing iOS application](https://github.com/thegamingart/TouchTracker)

Comment: I tried to call it, but found only `setNeedsDisplayInRect(<#invalidRect: NSRect#>)`, and after calling that in any function the view completely stops updating, even after hiding/bringing it back. That looks strange for me, so I just don't know what to do

Comment: I added a link to the method above

Comment: It doesn't help at all. But now when I hide/reopen the window, the lines draw as usually, but when i start drawing again, they disappear

Comment: You should probably look at the above tutorial, judging by the code above, there's not much we can tell about the actual drawing logic that is happening. I'm sure at this point though that something in the actual drawing logic is happening wrong or occurring in a way you expect by the life cycle of a view does not.

Comment: I've also added a sample application for iOS above that draws per user touches/drag. This application should translate to OS X fairly easy and the same logic applies. Use it as a reference for how to draw and what you need to do.

Comment: If you can't emulate the functionality above I'm not sure how we can help you. I would definitely take some time out to learn the language and app life cycle before trying to address an issue like this.

Comment: The answer to the question above is pretty much there though defining what to do and how to do it

Comment: ok, I understand. I just thought that app will be enough easy for a beginner, but, as I can see, I've mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`display()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/display) method to force the view to reload.

Just call that function on your main-view.

**Documentation**

> If the receiver isn’t opaque, this method backs up the view hierarchy
>   to the first opaque ancestor, calculates the portion of the opaque
>   ancestor covered by the receiver, and begins displaying from there.

Comment: I wrote that to `mouseDragged` and after running it gave an error "fatal error: Array index out of range"

Comment: display is not something you want to call, display is used for other scenarios (like calculating heights before views and subview hierarchies have been drawn on screen).